# What is a newer alternative to Spring's OpenSessionInViewInterceptor?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I was reading through Spring's "hibernate support" documentation and saw that both `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` and `OpenSessionInViewFilter` are deprecated, it says

> Deprecated.   as of Spring 4.3, in favor of Hibernate 4.x/5.x

but not more detail; since I always like to keep up to date with the frameworks I use, it bugs me not knowing what would I do in such scenario I could need one of these classes (without working with deprecated stuff), I know that the trend nowadays is to use REST architecture, in which case any of these would render useless but still, it's always good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says right there, the alternative is to upgrade Hibernate:

> Deprecated. as of Spring 4.3, **in favor of Hibernate 4.x/5.x**

In other words, this class is deprecated:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
```

In favour of this one:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
```